# MPMoviePlayerController: how to read a temporary video file

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, progressive-download

My application is relatively simple: User selects a video from a list, he selects some presets and it is automatically exported into application's temp directory.

To preview exported files, I launch a MPMoviePlayerController about 10 seconds after the video file is exported. It is a sort of progressive download.

However, the MPMoviePlayerController sends a notification that playback is finished. How can I do to playback when another process is writing a video?

Comment: So you are trying to play a local file which is not completely written at this point?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly my problem. I will try to use AVPlayer if I cannot see another solution.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution to this problem?

Comment: I resolved this problem by adding codec metadata at the beginning of the file and not at the end.